# How to associate a Shapefile (.shp) attribute table input (@data) to its respective polygon ID in a Large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, polygon, shapefile

Thanks in advance for helping me with this issue...

When opening a *shapefile (.shp)* object in R using `rgdal::readOGR()` it results in a "S4 object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame". Inside that object, I have two main contents of interest: `@data` (list, S3: data.frame) and `@polygons` (list of IDs from 0 to 398). Both of those are 399 rows of lenght (because my shapefile has 399 polygons [cities]).

I'd like to correlate the Polygon ID with the corresponding line in the @data attribute table, but they are not in the same order, neither does the row number in the attribute table matches the rows of the @polygon list.

Specifically, I'd like to create a new column in the dataframe containing these polygon's IDs.

I hope I make myself understood. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Try using the `sf` package to read spatial data.  https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/  It is far easier and more intuitive than spatialdataframes.